# Is it possible to fade-out the end of a text line in CSS?

Tags: css

I've seen various examples of how to fade out a line of text in CSS. However, these all involve a gradient overlay which matches the background colour.  Usually this might be white for example, where the background is also white.

However, if you have a gradient based background with some colour for example, the fade doesn't work in this approach.  I can not find any other methods to achieve this desired look.

Is there not a way to fade out text to become transparent itself in a gradient method applied to it directly?

Comment: remember that there really is no 'fade out' - all one can do is fade to background to create the illusion of the 'fade out; Granted that are ways of coding transparency.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, yellow);
}
h2 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#000000 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>
    test test test test test
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Really nice solution. I've updated a bit the snippet, hope it's ok :)

Comment: Can&#39;t you fade from `transparent` to `inherit`? Or fade opacity?

Answer (score 14):

There is a sleek solution which uses `mask-image`. Yes, it uses a `linear-gradient()`, however, because it works with pure transparencies, no knowledge of the background color is necessary:

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%, rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

Works for me in Chrome and [caniuse for `mask-image`](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image) looks not bad.

Comment: This is beautiful goddamn wizardry. I was skeptical since this answer doesn't have many upvotes, but this is _perfect_ and insanely easy to implement. My sincerest thanks!

Comment: Any idea if there's any major performance downside to using this dozens to hundreds of times on a page?